# How to avoid tap event for transparent part of texture?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am checking texture rect of my object to handle tap event, but since my texture is of irregular shape, it takes tap when I tap on transparent part. I want the object behind it to take tap. There are some solution like checking pixel value, which effects performance. Is there any efficient solution?

Answer (score 0):

checking the pixel is a pretty efficient solution. if you are keeping it in memory. if you don't want to do that, you could use bounding boxes/polygons linked to the texture used.